# How to check if a dynamic array is empty

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have a procedure declared like so:

```
procedure MyProc(List: Array of string);
```

I want to know how to check if the `List` parameter is empty.

For example:

```
procedure MyProc(List: Array of string);
begin
  if List=[] then // here I want to check if the List array is empty
  //do something
  else 
  //do something else
end;
```

How I can do this?

Comment: You should have written `MyProc(const List: array of string)` because in your code, all strings are copied into a temporary array before calling the `MyProc` procedure. And `if pointer(List)=nil then` is the fastest way to check that a dynamic array is empty.

Comment: `pointer(list)` abandons type-safety and relies on implementation detail

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez AFAIK without the const specifier, array is copied to a new (temp) one only if you modify it in MyProc, not before calling (dynamic arrays follow COW strategy like strings).

Comment: @Bozzy I was indeed not exact: all strings are not copied into a temporary array. But the refcount of the string is increased, then decreased, so there are two unnecessary RTL calls. So if you use `const` you don't have those AddRef/DecRef hidden procedure calls.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can use the [`Length`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Length) function

```
procedure MyProc(List: Array of string);
begin
  if Length(List)=0 then // is empty ?
  //do something
  else 
  // do something else
end;
```

Answer (score 12):

Empty arrays are equal to `nil`:

```
if List = nil then // it's empty
```

(That also means `SetLength(List, 0)` and `List := nil` are equivalent commands.)

Empty arrays have a last index that's less than the first index, which for the *open array* in your example means having a negative last index:

```
if High(List) < 0 then // it's empty
```

That means that if you want to avoid running a loop on an empty array, you don't have to do anything special. Just write the loop as you normally would:

```
for i := Low(List) to High(List) do // won't run if List is empty
```

Comment: are you sure about `if List = nil then`? this line does not compile.

Comment: `if pointer(List)=nil then` is the fastest way to check that a dynamic array is empty (fastest than `length(List)=0`)

Comment: @RRUZ: that is because `List = nil` works only for `dynamic arrays` (like in the title of this question), but not for `open arrays` (like in the example of this question). The poster is mixing dynamic and open arrays.

Comment: I don't like the idea of using `Assigned(List)` or any other variation on that theme to check if an array is **empty**. Compare for example the `TList` class. There's a significantly different meaning between `MyTList = nil` and `MyTList.Count = 0`. As much as something that doesn't exist cannot have any items - the fact that it doesn't _exist_ can be a significant _error_. So I'd rather stick with `Length(List)`, and better yet `for I := Low(List) to High(List)` with the advantage that it's the same for _all three_ kinds of arrays. (+1 anycase for: "won't run if List is empty")

Answer (score 2):

Personally I always write

```
if Assigned(List) then
```

rather than

```
if List<>nil then
```

because I believe it reads better, and not just for dynamic arrays.

---

That answers the question for *dynamic* arrays, but your example is an *open* array, so there are two possible questions here.

For open arrays I would use `Length()` or `high()` to take decision based on the size of the array.  I would not be seduced by arguments that `Pointer(List)<>nil` is quicker than `Length(List)<>nil`. The difference in speed between these options will not be discernible and so you should use the most clear and readable option.

Comment: I agree. This is more Delphi-like than the alternative. +1

Comment: I don't like the idea of using `Assigned(List)` or any other variation on that theme to check if an array is **empty**. Compare for example the `TList` class. There's a significantly different meaning between `MyTList = nil` and `MyTList.Count = 0`. As much as something that doesn't exist cannot have any items - the fact that it doesn't _exist_ can be a significant _error_. So I'd rather stick with `Length(List)`, and better yet `for I := Low(List) to High(List)` with the advantage that it's the same for _all three_ kinds of arrays.

Comment: @Craig In practice I don't think one would easily get dynamic arrays and objects mixed up but I do take your point.